# What does "VN" optional argument in contour function stand for?

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure, contour

The documentation for it is scarce (in `contourc` function):

> `VN` is either a scalar denoting the number of lines to compute or a vector containing the values of the lines.  If only one value is wanted, set `'VN = [val, val]'`; If `VN` is omitted it defaults to `10`.

I've tried a few examples, it somehow affects the amount of lines around my contour.
Does it denote how smooth my function's slope will be?
What does `VN` stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

The `contourc` function does not change your `data`. It just plots them. Using the VN argument you can control how many contour lines are created between the highest and lowest point of the topography/function you are plotting.

If you set VN to a scalar integer value, it directly specifies the number of lines. `VN=20` will create 20 levels between the highest and lowest point of your topography.

If you specify a vector of values you can exactly control at which values in your `data` the contour line is produced. You should take care that the values are in between `min(data(:))` and `max(data(:))`. Otherwise the lines will not be drawn. Example `VN=linspace(min(data(:)),max(data(:)),10)` will create the exact same contour lines as not specifying VN.

### Examples

To illustrate the effect of VN parameter I give some examples here. I use the `contour` function to directly plot the lines instead of just calculating them with `contourc`but the effect is the same.

```
% Create coordinate grid
[x,y]=meshgrid(-2:0.1:2,-2:0.1:2);
% define a contour function
z=x.^2 + 2*y.^3;
% create a figure
figure();
% plot contour
contour(x,y,z);
% make axis iso scaled
axis equal
```

#### Example 1

Using the contour command without VN argument produces the following result

```
contour(x,y,z);
```

[image: <code>contour(x,y,z)</code>]

#### Example 2: VN=50

Setting VN to 50
    contour(x,y,z,50);

[image: <code>contour(x,y,z,50)</code>]

#### Example 3: VN= vector

Setting VN explicitly to the contour values vector is used here to limit contour lines to a rather narrow range of z data:

```
contour(x,y,z,linspace(-0.5,0.5,10));
```

[image: <code>contour(x,y,z,linspace(-0.5,0.5,10))</code>]